# Replace a certain group in a pyspark dataframe column with a random item from a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, random, pyspark

Let's say the dataframe looks like this:

```
ls = [
    ['1', -9.78],
    ['2', 5.38],
    ['1', 8.86],
    ['2', -0.47],
    ['1', -0.19],
    ['1', 4.78],
    ['1', -9.23],
    ['2', -89.32]
]
test = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=['col1', 'col2']))
test.show()
```

output:

```
+----+------+
|col1|  col2|
+----+------+
|   1| -9.78|
|   2|  5.38|
|   1|  8.86|
|   2| -0.47|
|   1| -0.19|
|   1|  4.78|
|   1| -9.23|
|   2|-89.32|
+----+------+
```

I want to replace all row where the value in col1 == 1 with random pick from a list of items: ['a', 'b', 'c'] (with replacement).

For example, the result would look like this:

```
+----+------+
|col1|  col2|
+----+------+
|   a| -9.78|
|   2|  5.38|
|   a|  8.86|
|   2| -0.47|
|   c| -0.19|
|   b|  4.78|
|   a| -9.23|
|   2|-89.32|
+----+------+
```

I'm new to Pyspark and I'm quite confused about when to use the operations like when(), where(), withColumn(), select() etc. I have searched through this site, but I can't find answer to my question, so I really hope someone could help!

Comment: You can use `pyspark.sql.functions.rand()` but there are 2 caveats. 1) Columns can't be mixed type, so you'd have to cast `col1` to be `StringType()`. 2) The random number would be recomputed every time there is an action taken so unless you set a seed (or write to disk), you will have random results each time.

Comment: @pault thanks for your comment, I already did the casting in my code (not in this example). Even though I knew the existence of pyspark.sql.functions.rand(), I'm struggling to do the conditioning on col1 and then pick a random item from a list of items as described above. Can you help me with a full code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to randomly pick a value from your list. Using [`pyspark.sql.functions.rand()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.rand) you can generate a uniform random number between 0 and 1. Based on the value of the random value chosen, you can select an index from your list.

For example, in your case where there are 3 items in your list:

- Pick the `'a'` if the random number is less than 1/3
- Pick the `'b'` if the random number is less than 2/3
- Otherwise pick `'c'`

Here is a function that can be used to generalize this for any length pick list:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand, when

def pickRandomValue():
    picklist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    N = len(picklist)
    r = rand()
    c = when(r <= 1.0/N, picklist[0])
    for i in range(1, N-1):
        c = c.when(r <= (i+1.0)/N, picklist[i])
    c = c.otherwise(picklist[-1])
    return c
```

Now use [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to modify `col1`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

test = test.withColumn(
    "col1", 
    when(
        col("col1") == 1,
        pickRandomValue()
    ).otherwise(col("col1").cast("string"))
)
test.show()
#+----+------+
#|col1|  col2|
#+----+------+
#|   c| -9.78|
#|   2|  5.38|
#|   c|  8.86|
#|   2| -0.47|
#|   b| -0.19|
#|   a|  4.78|
#|   a| -9.23|
#|   2|-89.32|
#+----+------+
```

However, I must reiterate a ["use with caution" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297551/replace-a-certain-group-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-column-with-a-random-item-from-a#comment99207920_56297551) about random numbers in spark. Since spark is lazy the call to `rand()` will be repeated each time an action is taken. To demonstrate this, here is the result of a second call to `show()`:

```python
test.show()
#+----+------+
#|col1|  col2|
#+----+------+
#|   c| -9.78|
#|   2|  5.38|
#|   b|  8.86|
#|   2| -0.47|
#|   b| -0.19|
#|   b|  4.78|
#|   b| -9.23|
#|   2|-89.32|
#+----+------+
```

As you can see, the results are different.